# Spotify - Search Exception 404

Tags: spotify, spotipy

given these lists:

```
owner_ids = []
playlist_name = []
playlist_ids = []
```

I am querying the `search` `endpoint` in Spotify, using the following `function`

```
def query_playlists(query):

    results = sp.search(q=query, type='playlist')

    playlist_items = results['playlists']['items']

    for item in playlist_items:
       playlist_name.append(item['name'])
       playlist_ids.append(item['id'])
       owner = item['owner']
       owner_ids.append(owner['id'])
       results = [[sp.user_playlist(username, playlist_id) for username in owner_ids] for playlist_id in playlist_ids]

    print results
```

but I get the following error:

`spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 404, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/12128526200/playlists/1ESwfz8otcu5uk5bNp3Mzq:
 Not found.`

Is this a bug or my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are searching for combinations of users and playlists that don't exist.= in `sp.user_playlist`. for each iteration of the loop, you are appending to a global `owner_ids` list and then iterating over it in the list comprehension. So at the second loop iteration, you will get combos that don't make sense, i.e. URLs that don't exist (404 not found).